# Cannot resolve symbol Static

Tags: python, django, django-templates

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'search/style.css' %}">
```

This is the code and I am getting error in loading static file in this part

```
href="{% static 'search/style.css' %}
```

error cannot resolve directory "{%static search

Comment: show traceback please

Comment: -static
  -search
    -images
       -style.css

Answer (score 0):

Are your settings pointing to that (`search/style.css`)directory?  You'll need something like the following in your app's settings.py:

```
...

STATIC_URL = '/search/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'search')
```